# Flutter Provider Variable Doesn't Change

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I'm using flutter provider package. I made a function for changing the value of a variable (setUserInfo) and I call it from Future function (after getting the response from the API), and set a getter (getUsername) to be called from the UI to get that value. When I use print in the first function to display the new value I see the value has changed, but when I call the the getter to get the value it returns null (so it doesn't actually change). I got this error:

> A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
> 'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
> Failed assertion: line 298 pos 10: 'data != null'

Provider class:

```
class LoginProvider extends LoginService with ChangeNotifier {
String _username;
void setUserInfo(username) {
    _username = username;
    print(_username);
    notifyListeners();
  }

get getUsername{
return _username;
}
/*
....
  */
```

UI

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var loginProvider = Provider.of<LoginProvider>(context);
    return Drawer(
        child: Container(
/*
 ..
  */
                  ListTile(
                    trailing: DrawerButton(),
                    title: Text(
                      loginProvider.getUsername,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                    ),
                  ), 
/* 
... 
*/
```

Comment: where are you calling `setUserInfo`

Comment: also you can do a little null check like this in your text widget `loginProvider?.getUsername ?? 'Name is null'`

Comment: I call it in a function in another class, and it's a future function as I state above

Comment: 'Name is null' returned

Comment: if it's a Future function that returns a value, maybe you need to wrap it with a FutureBuilder or FutureProvider so the UI display it when you actually have the value

Comment: the value have been returned from the future function because I can print it when I call setUserInfo. The provider acts like notifyListeners() is not working! @EdwynZN

Comment: can you post the part of the widget tree where you update the value or use setUserInfo